# showing the fraction of samples in a bin converges to the expected fraction with probability 1

Tags: statistics

I came across the following question and I just can't think of a proof.
We defined the histogram as being
$$
h_n(x)=\frac{1}{n(a_{j}-a_{j-1})}\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{(a_{j-1}, a_j]}(x_i)
$$
where
$$
1_{(a_{j-1}, a_j]}(x_i)=\cases{1,\quad x\in(a_{j-1},a_j]\\0,\quad\text{otherwise}},
$$
and $n$ is the number of data points.
The question is:

> Let $h_n$ be the scaled histogram of a sample $X_1,...,X_n$ from a distribution with density $f$. The partition of the histogram is given by $a_0<a_1<\cdots<a_m$. Prove that for $x\in(a_{j-1},a_j]$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} h_n(x)=\frac{1}{n(a_{j}-a_{j-1})}\int_{a_{j-1}}^{a_j} f(s)\,ds$ with probability 1.

I think I have the intuition but I just find the notation very cryptic and I'm really sure even how to start this kind of proof. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The title of your post is a bit misleading since the question you've asked is about showing the fraction of samples in a bin converges to the expected fraction with probability 1. This is just the strong law of large numbers. There's also a typo in your expression for the limit of $h_n$, there shouldnt be an $n$ in the denominator.

Which part of the notation is confusing?

EDIT:

The strong law of large numbers states that the average of $n$ independent random variables with expectation $\mu$ and finite variance converges to it's expectation $\mu$ with probability 1. Expressed differently, for all $\epsilon > 0$:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_i^n X_i - \mu \right | > \epsilon \right) = 0$$

Comment: Hey, thank you for the feedback. I changed the title. About the expression of $h_n$ I divided by $n$ as it supposed to be the scaled diagram. Would you mind sharing how you would go about proving the statement?

Comment: Note that the division by $n$ doesnt make sense since it appears as the value of a limit at $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: I added a few more details let me know if there is still some confusion.